# Hierarchical queries with Mongo using $graphLookup, how to find all children?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have table model User

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
telegramId_parent: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
    telegramId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    telegramName: {
      type: String,
    },
   
  }
);
```

Data in DataBase

```
   [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId('63e8b3951e2a'),
        telegramId: 111,
        telegramName: 'ParentTest',
        telegramId_parent: null,
      },
      {
        _id: new ObjectId('63e8fa887473'),
        telegramId: 100,
        telegramName: 'child1',
        telegramId_parent: 200,
      },
      {
        _id: new ObjectId('45a2ec90e'),
        telegramId: 101,
        telegramName: 'child2"',
        telegramId_parent: 200,
      },
      {
        _id: new ObjectId('63c92e'),
        telegramId: 102,
        telegramName: 'child1-1"',
        telegramId_parent: 100,
      },
      {
        _id: new ObjectId('63e96'),
        telegramId: 200,
        telegramName: 'Name1',
        telegramId_parent: 111,
      },
    ];
```

I want to get child user.telegramId=200 with depth =3

hat is, I expect this result:

```
 {
    _id: new ObjectId('63e96'),
    telegramId: 200,
    telegramName: 'Name1',
    telegramId_parent: 111,
    childs:[
        {
            _id: new ObjectId('63e8fa887473'),
            telegramId: 100,
            telegramName: 'child1',
            telegramId_parent: 200,
          },
          {
            _id: new ObjectId('45a2ec90e'),
            telegramId: 101,
            telegramName: 'child2"',
            telegramId_parent: 200,
          },
          {
            _id: new ObjectId('63c92e'),
            telegramId: 102,
            telegramName: 'child1-1"',
            telegramId_parent: 100,
          },
    ]
   }
```

My query:

```
User.aggregate([
    { $match: { telegramId: 200 } },
    {
      $graphLookup: {
        from: 'Users',
        startWith: '$telegramId',
        connectFromField: 'telegramId',
        connectToField: 'telegramId_parent',
        as: 'child',
        maxDepth: 3,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

The result should be like,

```
  200->>> UserId
  /\
 /  \
100 101
/
```

/
102
Any help will be appreciated for getting the hierarchical results with level?

I am not able to get the result as expected.
but for some reason he does not find it and I get such a result

```
 {
            _id: new ObjectId('63e96'),
            telegramId: 200,
            telegramName: 'Name1',
            telegramId_parent: 111,
            childs:[]
    }
```

why doesn't he find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $graphLookup 'from' field takes a collection name, not a mongoose model.  Mongoose automatically downcases the model name when creating the collection, so use 'users' instead of 'Users':

```
User.aggregate([
    { $match: { telegramId: 200 } },
    {
      $graphLookup: {
        from: 'users',
        startWith: '$telegramId',
        connectFromField: 'telegramId',
        connectToField: 'telegramId_parent',
        as: 'child',
        maxDepth: 3,
      },
    },
  ]);
```